# YouTube Music not playing artist album-by-album

Tags: youtube, google-play-music, youtube-music

In Google Play Music, when you would select an artist in My Library with multiple albums, it would play the songs album by album, in the order depicted below:
[image: Google Play Music]

However, in YouTube Music, it automatically shuffles the songs (like below) and there is no option to play the songs album by album:
[image: YouTube Music]

Is there a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.
There is NO option to play by album when on the `ARTISTS` screen.
The only option one has is to click on `Shuffle all`

[image]

## The solution

#### **To play the songs album by album in YouTube Music**

While in the artist screen (or any other screen), pick and right click one of the songs that you like and from the pop-up menu choose `Go to album`

[image]

When in the album click on the 3 dots (kebab menu) next to the `REMOVE FROM LIBRARY` and from the pop-up make a choice between `Play next` and `Add to queue`

[image]

### **OR**

Go to `Library --> ALBUMS`

Once in the `ALBUMS` screen, right click on the album you want.

[image]

From the options on the pop menu you can once more choose between `Play next` and `Add to queue`.

#### **Difference between `Play next` and `Add to queue`**

- **`Play next`**
  This choice will add the whole album right **after the currently playing song**
- **`Add to queue`**
  This choice will add the whole album **at the end of the queue**.

Comment: Have you tried the given solutions? Did they work for you? If not we could try finding out why. If yes, please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: I don't see how this is  a solution. I don't want to just add it to the queue to play one time.

Comment: *"I don't see how this is a solution."* I don't see why not.  *"I don't want to just add it to the queue to play one time."* YouTube Music acts as a radio which means songs play and stay in queue till deleted. So it is not one time. Your other option is creating playlists and adding full albums. Also, your question is *"YouTube Music not playing artist album-by-album... it automatically shuffles the songs"*. That is what the answer solves. In any case. I'd be happy to know if you can find a better alternative.